# Hiding Border On HTML Button

Tags: html

I'm having a little trouble with a button I'm making as part of a SharePoint site. It currently appears like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whtwl.jpg

I would like to edit my code so the grey border does not appear around the blue image but I've had no luck getting anything to work. My current code is pretty simple and can be found below:

```
<button onclick="HideShow()" type="button">
<img src="Training%20Libraries.png" style="width: 117px; height: 33px;"/>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 border: none;
```

for the button

Comment: Would you be able to clarify where that should go in the code? I tried that in a couple different spots and it didn't seem to have any effect.